# How to set cookie in django redirect under HTTPS?

Tags: django, cookies, https

I'm making an app (like single sign on) that:

1. user request to login service A
2. get username/password from db and login A by web_api of A
3. make a HttpResponseRedirect, set cookie and return to user.

> User <==> app <==> service(https)

The whole process is good in HTTP. but when service A is under HTTPS then it's not work. The cookie set in step 3 will disappear when user be redirected to A website.

```
response = HttpResponseRedirect('https://xxxx/service')
response.set_cookie(key=cookie.name, value=cookie.value, 
domain=cookie.domain, path=cookie.path, expires=cookie.expires)
```

Comment: Which value in `cookie.domain` and is it equal to domain in ssh key?

Comment: Does any one has solution on this, even for me also django 1.8.17 has the issue ?

Comment: Maybe you'll get the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476922/how-to-make-django-sessionid-cookie-as-secure